# limit qwtPlotZoomer selection to canvas boundaries

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

The default behavior of `qwtPlotZoomer` seems to be that you can select a rectangle which exceeds the axis scale boundaries and canvas size, as seen in this screenshot from the `realtime` example:

[image: QwtPlotZoomer rectangle out of canvas bounds]

I'd like to restrict the edges of the selection to be equal to the canvas or `zoomRect`boundaries. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Based on Uwe's advice, I overloaded the `move()` function as follows, which prevents the picker's rect from being drawn off-screen.

```
void QZoomer::move(const QPoint& pos)
{
    // bound the picker selection to the zoom base so you can't zoom off screen
    QPoint boundedPos = pos;

    if (boundedPos.x() > plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().right())  boundedPos.setX(plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().right());
    if (boundedPos.x() < plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().left())   boundedPos.setX(plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().left());
    if (boundedPos.y() < plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().top())    boundedPos.setY(plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().top());
    if (boundedPos.y() > plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().bottom()) boundedPos.setY(plot()->canvas()->contentsRect().bottom());

    QwtPlotPicker::move(boundedPos);
}
```

another way is to override the zoom function and bound the `rect` to the `zoomBase`. This limits the actual zoom to the zoom base, but still draws the picker outside the lines.

```
void Zoomer::zoom(const QRectF& rect)
{
    // bound the zooming rect to the zoomBase dimensions
    QRectF boundedRect = rect & zoomBase(); 
    QwtPlotZoomer::zoom(boundedRect);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the move() method and bound the position to the contentsRect() of the canvas there ( or maybe better use the pickArea - what usually is the same ).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Blackwood I can see why you'd think this, but in this case the answer was the helpful guidance I was looking for and sufficient for me to solve the problem.